# Change background color of the menu of active page and its sub-pages

Tags: javascript

I am changing the background color of the current menu item.

For example i am on abc.com/tours so the color of the menu-item "tours" is changed to pink using the following code.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[href]").each(function() {
if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass("change_color_pink");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

How ever if i go to abc.com/tours/australia i want the menu-item "tours" to remain pink. What should i do?

NOTE: /tours/australia is a link inside /tours

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify how you use the colours? There seems to be a disagreement about this. Will the active menu item(s) always be pink? Do you have one specific colour for each category?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the color value in a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or in a [url query string](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) and read the state back into your function on the following pages.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Better than the ones in the links I provided?

Comment: There is no need to introduce state here, accordingly to the question, the main category is already represented in the url.

Comment: Where do they state that the colour is randomly set? If is not random, there is no need to persist the colour.

Comment: "ugh, dynamically != randomly" exactly. So if they know the colour they are using for their menu, they don't have to persist it over page requests.

Comment: They have to persist if the color has changed over page requests. It has or it hasn't, the next page needs to know on page load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48121/discussion-between-alex-and-jeremyjjbrown)

Answer (score 0):

If your model consists of an url and a menu consisting of html elements, you first have to introduce logic that can parse your url into relevant parts. This should be quite simple if your format is domain.com/child/child/child/... When you have this data, in an array for example, you have to project it to your html structure. Assuming that your menu markup is hierarchical, the algorithm would probably be not much harder then to iteratively find the top html element, do your modifications and search for the next top element inside the current element.

Comment: they are asking how to pass state between pages.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown But there are no state dependencies. It is all in the url.

Comment: Assuming that they are using random colours. And that would be very odd.

Comment: No, if it is not random, your solution is pointless. There is no information they can not get from the pure url itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48120/discussion-between-alex-and-jeremyjjbrown)

Comment: Sorry I'm not interested.